# Tensorflow can be used in Pycharm, but cannot find reference `xxx` in __init__.py

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, tensorflow2.0

I am using tensorlfow 2.0 in Pycharm 2019, it seems that it can be used normally, and the code will be completed automatically. But Pycharm keeps showing　`cannot find reference xxx in __init__.py` .  The following image is the result of my run. by the way, my OS is Ubuntu 16.04, And I use anaconda to manage my python.
 Please help me, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Should be fixed in 2019.3 release. See the relevant ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37589

Btw 2019.3 release candidate is already available, feel free to grab it from https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/